# CURL certificate validation vs openssl s_client?

Tags: ssl, certificate, pki

I've had an issue where connecting with curl to https://server failed with:

curl: (60) server certificate verification failed.

but initiating a connection with openssl s_client worked fine.

The problem was somehow related to the server side, but I do not understand what could cause curl to reject the connection while openssl s_client was ok. OpenSSL 1.0.2s-fips

Help ?

Comment: `openssl s_client` at least in 1.0.2 does not check that the server name matches the certificate while curl does. `openssl s_client` also continues even if the verification failed, i.e. it might look that *"openssl s_client was ok"* even if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks, openssl did say verify=1 for each Intermediate cert. The problem was... the actual server cert had expired. Openssl final check (session start) also said "Verify return code: 0 (ok)"  So it was the actual cert, not the "chain".

Answer (score 0):

Bummer. it was not the chain but the actual cert that had expired.
Somehow openssl s_client did not catch that. Nor did I.
(openssl s_client -showcerts did show chain certs but not server cert)